# finding value of column after ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

Consider this statement:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE d=d+1;
```

I need the value of `d`.

Is it possible to obtain it without performing a further `SELECT`?

There is a unique index on `a,b,c`. Would this index be used for better performance? This table will have a large number of rows.

Comment: You could do this in a stored procedure maybe, but there's no way to get it out of the same statement that I'm aware of.

Comment: If you have composite unique index `a+b+c` then your query may fail sometimes, when `c=c+1` doesn't make an unique combination.

Comment: Oh, you are right, is not C, is another field, D, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you will be running both queries using the same connection, You can use the `LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)` function to set the current value of `d`, and check the value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` together with the `ROW_COUNT()` function to find out if the record was inserted or updated:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c)
VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE d = LAST_INSERT_ID(d + 1);

SELECT IF(ROW_COUNT() = 2, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 0 /*default value*/) ;
```

You can also use session variables:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c)
VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE d = @tmp := (d + 1);

SELECT IF(ROW_COUNT() = 2, @tmp, 0 /*default value*/) ;
```